# Why is the Map Feedback API from Here throwing a validationException

Tags: php, curl, here-api

I'm trying to get started with the Here Map Feedback API and I wanted to create a map feedback, but everytime I'm trying to insert an isocc (ISO Country Code, eg. 'USA') I'm getting a response with 'validationException' and 'FEEDBACK_PROPERTY_ISOCC_COUNTRY_MISMATCH'.

Response is like following:

```
[...]
["properties"]=>
    object(stdClass)#19 (10) {
      ["validationException"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#22 (2) {
          ["severity"]=>
          int(1)
          ["id"]=>
          string(40) "FEEDBACK_PROPERTY_ISOCC_COUNTRY_MISMATCH"
        }
      }
    }
[...]
```

---

UPDATE:
My request (JSON formatted) goes like this:

```
[{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[
        "<LATITUDE>",
        "<LONGITUDE>",
        0
    ],
    "properties":{
        "v":"2.7",
        "appId":"<MY_CLIENT_ID>",
        "error":31,
        "useremail":"<USEREMAIL>",
        "isocc":"DEU",
        "roadname":"<MY_STREET>",
        "number":"<MY_STREET_NUMBER>",
        "phone":"<MY_PHONE_NUMBER>",
        "city":"<MY_CITY>"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Please provide your post request so that we can help you better.

Comment: Updated my post with the request I'm using

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your coordinates doesn't match with the country code you have provided. Coordinates are passed as longitude, latitude and not the other way around as you have in your request. Please correct it and retry.

```
[{
    "type":"Point",
    "coordinates":[
        "<LONGITUDE>",
        "<LATITUDE>",
        0
    ],
    "properties":{
        "v":"2.7",
        "appId":"<MY_CLIENT_ID>",
        "error":31,
        "useremail":"<USEREMAIL>",
        "isocc":"DEU",
        "roadname":"<MY_STREET>",
        "number":"<MY_STREET_NUMBER>",
        "phone":"<MY_PHONE_NUMBER>",
        "city":"<MY_CITY>"
    }
}]
```